# Possible infinite recursion in method?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code, why is it that it could create a possible infinite recursion, and why does the memory usage keep raising, and how to solve it ?

```
function waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction) {
    if (getElementByXPath(selectorTxt) == null) {
       var timeControl = setInterval (function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction);
                },
                300
            );
    } else {
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        actionFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `timeControl` is local to each *invocation* of the function `waitForKeyElements()` - i.e. the `timeControl` you set will not be the `timeControl` you clear. In other words, the timer you started with `setInterval` will never get cleared.

Moving it outside the function should solve it.

i.e.

```
var timeControl = -1;

function waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction) {
    if (getElementByXPath(selectorTxt) == null) {
       timeControl = setInterval (function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction);
                },
                300
            );
    } else {
        if(timeControl !== -1) clearInterval (timeControl);
        actionFunction();
    }
}
```

Also, as user Prinzhorn pointed out in the comment, starting a timer with setInterval in each invocation is bound to be troublesome. You should *really* be just doing a setTimeout to ensure things don't get out of hand.

Comment: No need to initialize `timeControl` as `-1`, neither `if(timeControl !== -1)`. It will "fail" silently when passed an invalid value

Comment: So according to Prinzhorn, what's the way to go ? Using setTimeout in place of setInterval, and removing the clearInterval line ?